# Is there any method to target ios gmail app using css?

Tags: css, ios, email, frontend, gmail

I've found methods to target Gmail App on Android, and method  to target ios. However I couldn't find a way to target specifically for gmail app on ios. Is there a way to do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

The iOS gmail client should just be treated the same as any webkit-based browser as apple forces every application to use Safari. You can just use device-size Media Queries to target the iPhone.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {     }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also affect android and webmails on mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, but why should that matter. You should be coding for the window size not the device type. Your CSS should work the same regardless of the OS. If you want to target the OS do it with JS.

Comment: This really does not answer the question asked; the question related to targeting the Gmail app on iOS specifically. This answer affects all device sizes below 480px for all clients that support the max-device-width media query.